# how to display buttons with paint method in code?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have this code in JAVA

`

```
public class Okno extends JFrame{
Pixel p;
private int x_zac, y_zac, x_kon, y_kon; //zaciatoca a koncova pozicia ciary
private int x_kruh, y_kruh; //suradnice kruhu
int poc_ciar=0;  // premenna na pocitanie poctu vytvorenych ciar
int cokreslim=0; // pomocna premenna na urcovanie kreslenia ciar=0 alebo kruhov=1

Canvas can = new Canvas();
JButton kruh = new JButton("kruh");
JButton ciara = new JButton("ciara");


GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
Kreslenie_vypocty vypocty = new Kreslenie_vypocty();

Okno(Pixel  p1){
    setSize(800, 700);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setResizable(false);


    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets= new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    add(kruh,c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets= new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    add(ciara,c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    add(can,c);

    can.setSize(500,700);
    can.setBackground(Color.gray);



    can.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {


        public void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int r) {
              x = x-(r/2);
              y = y-(r/2);
              g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
            }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        } 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            p.c.add(new Ciara());
            x_zac = e.getX();
            y_zac = e.getY();  
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            x_kon = e.getX();
            y_kon = e.getY();
            repaint();
            vypocty.vypocet_bodov(x_zac, y_zac, x_kon, y_kon, p, poc_ciar);
            poc_ciar++; 
        }
    });
    //can.setVisible(true);

    p=p1;


    kruh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cokreslim=1;
        }
    });

    ciara.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cokreslim=0;
        }
    });


}   
public void paint(Graphics g){  
    g=can.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    if (cokreslim==0)
        g.drawLine(x_zac,y_zac,x_kon,y_kon);
    else
        g.drawOval(x_zac-(50/2),y_zac-(50/2),50,50);}}`
```

When I have paint method in code, buttons are not displayed. But when I remove it, everithing is fine.

Screens:with paint method
 [image: with paint method]

without paint method
[image: without paint method]

..... when I click on canvas, one button is displayed

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of, you should call `super.paint(g)`...this is very important, as part of it's job is to paint the child components...

Having said that...You should avoid overriding `paint` especially of top level containers like `JFrame`, instead, you should create a custom component that extends from something like `JComponent` (like `JPanel` for example) and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.

You should also avoid painting to components that contain other components, unless you're planning on painting a background image of some kind, for example.

Instead, separate your containers, so you're painting doesn't end up under other components...unless thats what you're aming for, then you should carry on...

Take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details